# Why am I unable to scroll some questions?

Tags: support

I'm experiencing a strange behavior.

I'm unable to scroll some questions.

For example:
[How to use Map inside MapThread?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38023/how-to-use-map-inside-mapthread/38089)

I'm using Windows 8.1 with IE.

Am'I the only one?

Comment: Life is to short to use IE! :p

Comment: I am not using MSIE but could you describe the behavior a bit more?  Does the scroll bar not exist, not move, or does the page continuously jump back to the top?

Comment: I scrolled the question mentioned with no difficulty using IE on Windowws 8.1.

Comment: Yeah, this happens after you edit a comment. No controls work any more, though I don't know what exactly causes it (but it seems to be reproducible--I just edited this one, and it happened again). I rarely use IE (using it now on my laptop), so I assumed it was an IE issue. You can work around it by reloading the page. IE 11 seems a lot better in general than previous versions. Not great, exactly, but certainly more usable than Chrome, for instance.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard if you edit (and save) a comment, then you should find yourself unable to edit again, or to scroll, without reloading the page. The page is simply fixed in place, although the scroll bar exists.

Comment: I don't think it's related with editing a comment. For example, I just opened IE, then opened Math.SE web site and clicked a red notification in the toolbar. This opened this page showing the previous @OleksandrR. comment. Now I cannot see the title of this page, and I cannot use the visible scrollbar to show the title or my question... I found that selecting some text and dragging outside the window can sometimes help scrolling.